# Wordpress: List Authors total posts [code included] but need current month

Tags: php, wordpress

Below is the code that displays authors with a minimum of 20 posts and outputs the posts.

How can I modify it either
1) add a column for monthly posts or
2) same row and add a "," for posts current month?

```
//sort users descending by number of posts
$uc=array();
$blogusers = get_users_of_blog();
if ($blogusers) {
  foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
    $post_count = get_usernumposts($bloguser->user_id);
    $uc[$bloguser->user_id]=$post_count;
  }
  arsort($uc);
  foreach ($uc as $key => $value) {
    $user = get_userdata($key);
    $author_posts_url = get_author_posts_url($key);
    $post_count = $value;
if ($post_count > 20 )  echo '<br>';
if ($post_count > 21 )  echo '<a href="' . $author_posts_url .'">' . $user->user_login     . '</a> - '  . $post_count .  ' posts';

  }
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you'll likely need to edit the 'get_usernumposts' function to do one of two things.

Group by month.  I can't see the query that's being run to pull the posts out of the db, but you'd modify the query inside that function to use a GROUP BY clause.

Accept a second parameter for months:

```
function get_usernumposts($user_id, $month=NULL) {
```

Then create a loop around your present code that loops through each available month.

```
$months_array = array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", ... );

foreach ($months_array AS $month) {

    // ...

    $post_count = get_usernumposts($bloguser->user_id, $month);
```

Then modify the SQL query to also check for month if it was supplied to the function.

Comment: I'm not a coder so that's pretty hard for me to do. There is no get current month or anything similar from timestamp? $current_month = date('m');
URL: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts#Time_Parameters